# The SQL Server edition of the target server is unsupported, e.g. SQL Azure

Tags: database, installation, sites-9

Having performed a fresh installation of Sites 9, I keep getting the following error: `The SQL Server edition of the target server is unsupported, e.g. SQL Azure.`

[image]

This is shown when I confirm the regional and user settings ("Configure your preferred Language Settings" popup), when trying to create a new Publication (the save fails), etc.

The Event Viewer shows a lot of these events, but nothing useful:

[image]

```
The SQL Server edition of the target server is unsupported, e.g. SQL Azure.


Component: Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService
Errorcode: 0
User: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE

StackTrace Information Details:
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SqlServer.SqlInstaller.Install()
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SqlServer.SqlMessageBus.Initialize(Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Messaging.ScaleoutStream.Send(Func`2 send, Object state)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Notifications.NotificationsManager.BroadcastNotification(NotificationMessage notification)
   at Tridion.Web.UI.CME.TcmExtensions.EventHandlers.IdentifiableObjectEventHandler(IdentifiableObject subject, TcmEventArgs e, EventPhases phases)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Extensibility.EventSubscription.DeliverEvent(IEnumerable`1 subjects, TcmEventArgs eventArgs, EventPhases phase)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Extensibility.EventSystem.DeliverEvent(IEnumerable`1 subjects, TcmEventArgs eventArgs, EventDeliveryPhase deliveryPhase)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Extensibility.EventSystem.DeliverEvent(IdentifiableObject subject, TcmEventArgs eventArgs, EventDeliveryPhase deliveryPhase)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.IdentifiableObject.Save(SaveEventArgs eventArgs)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.IdentifiableObject.Save()
   at Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.CoreServiceBase.Save(IdentifiableObjectData deltaData, ReadOptions readBackOptions)
   at SyncInvokeSave(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.CoreServiceInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
```

The databases were indeed all created in Azure SQL, but according to the official [documentation](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Tridion%20Sites-v1&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-E55DBE7E-E436-4899-AC75-B412BCC16D69&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-BF0C63CF-A201-4C56-9305-534F2792C1A7.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-E55DBE7E-E436-4899-AC75-B412BCC16D69) it is supported. I have used the same for Web 8.5 and 8.1 previously without any issues. At first I thought it was because I added the databases to an Elastic Pool, but I get the same error for "standalone" databases as well.

Looking at the decrypted `Tridion.ContentManager.config` or the snap-in I see nothing wrong:

```
<database server="____.database.windows.net" name="____" username="____" password="____" authenticationMethod="Normal" />
```

[image]

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

I have made some progress by following the following KB article and SE question:

- https://gateway.sdl.com/apex/communityknowledge?articleName=000003104
- [Configuring SignalR message bus for 8.5 install](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/16892/configuring-signalr-message-bus-for-8-5-install)

But now am getting another error:

```
Provided ScaleoutMessageBusType 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.ServiceBus.ServiceBusMessageBus' must implement IMessageBus interface.

Component: BackplaneHub
Errorcode: 0
User: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE

StackTrace Information Details:
   at Sdl.SignalR.Backplane.Common.HubLoader.CreateMessageBus(String assembly, String scaleoutConfigurationType, String scaleoutMessageBusType, Boolean patchOnReceived, Object[] backplaneConfigurationParameters)
   at Sdl.SignalR.Backplane.Common.HubLoader.Load(IAppBuilder app, String assembly, String scaleoutConfigurationType, String scaleoutMessageBusType, String hubAssemblyName, Boolean patchOnReceived, Object[] backplaneConfigurationParameters)
   at Sdl.Web.Notification.BackplaneHub.IISHost.Startup.Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
```

The relevant content manager config section:

```
<signalrBackplaneHub messageBusType="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.ServiceBus.ServiceBusMessageBus" scaleoutConfigurationType="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.ServiceBusScaleoutConfiguration" assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.ServiceBus, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
    <backplaneConnectionParameters>
        <add parameter="Endpoint=sb://___servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=_____" />
        <add parameter="topicPrefix" />
    </backplaneConnectionParameters>
</signalrBackplaneHub>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your signalrBackplaneHub config is not valid. Use one described in documentation https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20Sites-v1/GUID-8B1C96F2-464E-442F-9727-3F4E7B21AF23

Comment: My bad, I overlooked that part. The system now works after following the docs.

Comment: Also see https://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/19708/88